# How to include a returned string in another method - java

Tags: java, string, methods, return

this is probably a very basic problem but as I am only a beginner, this is confusing me. I am trying to make capitalise the first letter of a string, which I have done with the following code:

```
public String capitalizeFirstLetter(String product){ 
    String productCap = product.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + product.substring(1); 
    return productCap; }
```

And then this capitalised version of the product just be placed in a letter writer method:

```
public void writeALetterChallenge(String nameFirst, String nameLast, String city, String    product, String company, double retail, int numItem){ 
UI.println("Dear " + nameFirst); 
UI.println(" You have been especially selected from the people of " + city); 
UI.println("to receive a special offer for "+ product); 
UI.println(productCap + " from " + company + " is a premium brand prodcut and");             UI.printf("retails for $%1.2f" + ". But, " + nameFirst + ",if you order your " + product + "\n", (retail)); 
UI.println("today, you can purchase it for just $" + (retail - (retail * 0.60)) + ", a saving of 60%!"); 
UI.println("As a special bonus, just for the " + nameLast + "family, if you order");     UI.println(numItem + " " + product + " today, you will get an additional 10% off - ");     UI.println("an amazing price for " + product + " of just $" + (retail - (retail * 0.70)) + "!"); 
UI.println(" "); 
UI.println("Hurry today and send in your order for " + product + " from " + company);     UI.println("and make these fantastic savings."); 
UI.println(" "); }
```

However my problem is that when I compile, I get the error that productCap cannot be found. So I've obviously missed something. How do I go about getting the productCap variable from the first method to be included in the second?

Any explanation on this would be great, thanks!

Comment: `productCap` is accessible in your method `capitalizeFirstLetter(String)` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call your method:

```
UI.println(capitalizeFirstLetter(product) + " from " + compan ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of this

```
  UI.println(productCap + " from " + company + " is a premium brand prodcut and");
```

you want to have this

```
  UI.println(capitalizeFirstLetter(product) + " from " + company + " is a premium brand prodcut and");
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can call your method as follows

```
UI.println(capitalizeFirstLetter(product) + " from " + company + " is a premium brand prodcut and");
```

Your variable `productCap` is local to method `CapitalizaFirstLetter()` and hence not accessible in another method.

To access the value of `productCap`, simply call `CapitalizeFirstLetter()` method so that it returns the value of `productCap`.